# How many ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfy the property $|x|+|y|\lt2019$?

Tags: inequality, permutations, combinations

How many ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfy the property $|x|+|y|\lt2019$? There must be a shorter way to get an answer here. $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers.

Comment: Can you sketch $|x| + |y| < 2$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing much. Just graphed it and found out the area of the square.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem

Comment: If I understand you right, finding the area of the square does not give you the number of ordered pairs as points on the boundary (such as $(0, 2019)$) are excluded. The answer is a square number, so you can use a similar approach by rotating the square by $45º$.

Comment: As $x,y$ are natural numbers, $|x|+|y|$ is the same thing as $x+y$.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at smaller cases, $$x=1 \implies y=1,2,3... 2017 \\ x=2\implies y=1,2,3...2016 $$ and in general for a given $x\in [1,2017]$, $y$ can range from $1$ to $2018-x$, so we just want $$\sum_{x=1}^{2017} 2018-x = 2035153$$

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1,\ldots,2018$ there are $k-1$ pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$ of positive integers such that $x+y=k$, one for each $x\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$. Thus, there are $$\sum_{k=1}^{2018}(k-1)=\sum_{k=0}^{2017}k=\frac{2017\cdot2018}2=2\,035\,153$$ solutions in positive integers.

For many of us, however, the natural numbers include $0$. That adds $2018$ solutions with $y=0$ and $x>0$, another $2018$ solutions with $x=0$ and $y>0$, and the solution $x=y=0$, for a total of $$2\,035\,153+4037=2\,039\,190$$ solutions.

Finally, if we allow $x$ and $y$ to range over all integers, as is suggested by the absolute values, there are $2\,035\,153$ solutions in the interior of each of the four quadrants, $2018$ on the positive $x$-axis, $2018$ on the positive $y$-axis, $2018$ on the negative $x$-axis, $2018$ on the negative $y$-axis, and one at the origin for a grand total of

$$4(2\,035\,153+2018)+1=8\,148\,685$$

solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you don't count $0$ as a natural number, though Brian's answer also addresses the case including $0$. This answer doesn't involve a large summation.

We know that $x+y<2019$ and that $x<x+y$ (since we assume that $y$ is not $0$). Hence, $\{x, x+y\}$ is a two element subset of $[2018]=\{1,2,3,\ldots, 2018\}$. Furthermore, every two element subset of $[2018]$ corresponds to an $(x,y)$ pair. Just pick the smaller element in your subset to be $x$ and the larger element to be $x+y$. Then the number of $(x,y)$ pairs is the number of two element subsets of $[2018]$, which is ${2018\choose 2}=\frac{2018\cdot 2017}{2}=2035153$.